# Может ли причастный оборот не согласоваться во времени с целым предложением?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вырезки из повествования, которое точно происходило в прошлом.

Например,

> ...их глазам **открылась** грандиозная панорама: дорога, уход**ящая***(-вшая)* вдаль, ласка**ющие***(-вшие)* берег волны...

> ...посмотрев на разговарива**ющих***(-вших)* между собой родственников, я решил не вмешиваться" (напоминаю, повествуется о давно прошедших событиях).

Answer (score 1):

Может. Согласование времен в русском языке, во-первых, не такое жесткое, как, например, в английском, (т. е. прошедшее, например, вполне может сочетаться с настоящим без какого-либо грамматического или семантического наполнения) — это следствие утраты русским глаголом большинства форм, не получается все так красиво согласовать.

А во-вторых, там, где согласование требуется и семантически значимо (причастия-приложения и определения, деепричастия в некоторых случаях — инфинитив), оно идет по относительному времени, т. е. настоящее и прошедшее берутся относительно момента действия основного глагола (это наш случай).

Ну и, наконец, когда согласование само по себе не помогает пониманию, смысл относительного времени передается видовой формой подчиненного глагола — это тоже имеет место в нашем примере (уходившая vs уходящая).

Ну и на всякий случай. В русском модификация семантики времени глагола лексическими средствами — вполне обычное дело: "завтра я иду в кино", "первый — пошел", "вчера я ходил" (не шел). И прочие возможности.

***Никакого жесткого согласования.***

Answer (score 0):

Полные причастия, являющиеся определениями, могут иметь относительную форму времени, которая определяется по отношению ко времени глагола-сказуемого.

Причастия настоящего времени выражают одновременность действий, обозначенных причастием и глаголом-сказуемым.

В приведенных вами примерах, причастие настоящего времени имеют значение прошедшего времени,  одновременное с действием глагола-сказуемого.

> ...их глазам открылась грандиозная панорама: дорога, уходящая вдаль, ласкающие берег волны...
>
> ...посмотрев на разговаривающих между собой родственников, я решил не вмешиваться.

В данном случае возможна замена причастий настоящего времени причастиями прошедшего времени без заметного изменения в значении.

Причастия прошедшего времени несовершенного и совершенного вида выражают действие, предшествовавшее действию, выраженному глаголом-сказуемым:

> — Экий бес девка! — закричал казак, расположившийся на соломе и мечтавший согреться остатками чая (Л.)
>
> Мы пошли на вал, возвышение, образованное природой и укрепленное частоколом (П.).

[См.: Современный русский язык Валгина Н.С. Розенталь Д.Э. Фомина М.И.](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-102.htm#i7025)